# Openapi generator to generate JsonNode type variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a following object definition in OpenApi v3.0.3. I am using java 17 + gradle with build.gradle.kts in Kotlin

```
     customPayload:
      type: object
      nullable: true
      example:
        date: 2022-12-16
        randomStuff: "random stuff"
```

Now currently OpenApi Generator will generate it like this:

```
@JsonProperty("customPayload")
  private JsonNullable<Object> customPayload = JsonNullable.undefined();
```

I would like to find a way to transform customPayload to JsonNode

Smt like this

```
  @JsonProperty("customPayload")
  private JsonNode customPayload;
```

So any good ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to change all `JsonNullable` objects to `JsonNode`, or all general `Object` types, or just this one `Object`?

Comment: Id hope for this one Object. But all alternatives are to be explored

Answer (score 1):

All of this can be done in your template.  I think the easiest way would be to use a [custom vendor extension](https://swagger.io/specification/#:%7E:text=read%3Apets-,Specification%20Extensions,-While%20the%20OpenAPI).  Create a custom extension called something like `x-render-asNode: true`, and then update your `pojo.mustache`.  You will need to add the JsonNode import to the top of your `pojo.mustache` and update the following line:

```
  {{#openApiNullable}}
  private {{>nullableDataType}} {{name}}{{#isNullable}} = JsonNullable.undefined(){{/isNullable}}{{^isNullable}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{{.}}}{{/defaultValue}}{{/isNullable}};
  {{/openApiNullable}}
```

Update the line to read as follows:

```
  {{#openApiNullable}}
  {{#vendorExtensions.x-render-asNode}}
  private JsonNode {{name}};
  {{/vendorExtensions.x-render-asNode}}
  {{^vendorExtensions.x-render-asNode}}
  private {{>nullableDataType}} {{name}}{{#isNullable}} = JsonNullable.undefined(){{/isNullable}}{{^isNullable}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{{.}}}{{/defaultValue}}{{/isNullable}};
  {{/vendorExtensions.x-render-asNode}}
  {{/openApiNullable}}
```

#### Explanation:

The vendor extension just needs to exist.  It doesn't need an actual value, however I've always preferred adding true, to assist in readability.  The mustache template takes a look at all vendor extensions, and sees if the list of extensions includes `x-render-asNode`.  It does this with the number(`#`) symbol.  If the extension exists, then it will render the object as a JsonNode.  If it doesn't exist, checked with the carrot(`^`) symbol, then it will render as usual.

#### Note:

The above change addresses the change to the field declaration.  However, you will need to make similar changes to the getter and setter methods to ensure they are taking in and returning `JsonNode` types as well.